# How to change YYYY-MM-DD format into DD-MM-YYYY in php

Tags: php, date

I am getting date format from database in YYYY-MM-DD format and I am using given code to convert this format.

```
$tempdate='2017-11-09';
$convertdate= date("d-m-y" , strtotime($tempdate));
```

but converted date is in 09-11-17, how can I convert this date into '09-11-2017'.

Comment: use "d-m-Y" as format

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempdate='2017-11-09';
$convertdate= date("d-m-Y" , strtotime($tempdate));
```

you need to write  the y uppercase to get the full year number

Answer (score 0):

change your line from

```
$convertdate= date("d-m-y" , strtotime($tempdate));
```

to

```
$convertdate= date("d-m-Y" , strtotime($tempdate));
```

Comment: Sorry dear its not working- still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make 'y' capital - > 'Y'